# Correct way to pass arguments to reducer in React+Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Seems like there's a lot of wrong ways of doing this and I'm fairly certain I'm trying to do this the wrong way (note this code doesn't work currently):

```
class SubmitLink extends React.Component<SubmitLinkProps, {}>{
    constructor(props: SubmitLinkProps) {
        super(props);

        this.urlToPass = "nothing";
    }

    urlToPass: string;
    handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.urlToPass = e.currentTarget.value;
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <div>hello world {this.props.url}</div>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text'></input>
            <button onClick={() => {
                this.props.submitlink(this.urlToPass);
            }}>submit</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Besides the fact the code doesn't work (urlToPass is undefined at runtime, unsure why) i tlooks like a tonne of work just to grab an input from a textfield. At the same time this is the only way I could find googling on how to do it but it really doesn't feel correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the  element contains its own state while React components also have their own internal state. The best way to handle this is to make the React component state the source of truth. You can read more about this best practice here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

In your case, it would be to do the following:

```
class SubmitLink extends React.Component<SubmitLinkProps, {}>{
    constructor(props: SubmitLinkProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { urlToPass: '' }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.setState({urlToPass: e.currentTarget.value});
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <div>hello world {this.props.url}</div>
            <input value={this.state.urlToPass} onChange={this.handleChange} type='text'></input>
            <button onClick={() => {
                this.props.submitlink(this.state.urlToPass);
            }}>submit</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that using ES6 syntax automatically binds 'this' to functions: myFunction = (params) => { code };

Comment: Good call out Adam!

Comment: hmm trying that code I get this error:     TS2339: Property 'urlToPass' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.

Comment: I just fixed the code. It was because I had `this.urlToPass` and not `this.state.urlToPass` as input to `submitLink`

Comment: Actually I tried that too, same error, not sure what's up with it. Seems to make sense syntax wise.

Comment: Oh wait, i think I know... haven't tested this out sorry but from the syntax `React.Component<SubmitLinkProps, {}>` what you are saying is that the Props will be of type `SubmitLinkProps` and the state will be of type `{}` and the empty object does not have the key `urlToPass`. You need to define a type with `urlToPass`, and replace the `{}` with that

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the handleChange method in your constructor. 
`this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`